# Am I creating memory leaks here?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

This is a view pager adapter.
I wonder whether I'm creating memory leaks there with those anonymous Runnables and TimerTasks

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(activity);

        imageView.setImageResource(slides[position].getStateOneResource());
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        animate(imageView, slides[position].getAllStates(), 0, false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 1000);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    } // End of instantiateItem
```

Comment: Why do you think you're causing a memory issue? Are you having performance problems? Generally in java you run into 'memory leak' (which it isn't a true memory leak) when you instantiate a large amount of large objects that don't get Garbage Collected, which it doesn't look like you're doing here.

Comment: I just wanted to know for theory reasons than because Im having a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) works well for finding memory leaks, and is quite easy to use.

(I can't comment yet so I had to post this as an answer :( )

Answer (score 1):

If you have any doubts, run this operation multiple times and everytime you run, take a memory snapshot. You can enable on the device an option to show on the screen how much memory is being used.

Edit: Take a look at this link: https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're creating memory leaks, but I think it's better to use the Context of the container.

Like this:

```
final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(container.getContext());
```

And for running a delayed operation on the main thread :

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(container.getContext().getMainLooper());

Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() {
       animate(imageView, slides[position].getAllStates(), 0, false);
    } 
};
mainHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 1000);
```